# SQL Join for ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Looking around, I can't seem to find a good solution to this. I've tried multiple Stored Procedures and variables, etc. but nothing seems to run fine. I have 2 tables. One is a UserShift, and the other is ShiftReasons.

ShiftReasons contains reasons why someone may be on shift, or off shift. The column I'm interested in is "ReasonID".

I want a stored procedure to return all userIDs who are currently on shift. You find this by (pseudo-code):

```
DECLARE currentTime;

reasons = SELECT ReasonID FROM ShiftReasons WHERE IsAbsence = 0;

SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Start < currentTime AND End > currentTime AND ReasonID (is one of) reasons.
```

Reasons is a list of IDs which relate to people being ON shift.

The problem I'm having is with the (is one of) part. Can anyone shed any help on this?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: use the 'IN' construct to check inside a list of values

Comment: When I've used a DECLARE reasons AS Table(Value INT), it's complained that reasons doesn't exist when I come to compare it?

Comment: @Matt Hello again ;) What is going on, why are you adding sql-server-2008 to this post and to other posts ? The question here is from 2011, so it might be from SQL Server 2008, 2005, 2000, ...

Answer (score 2):

Use IN

```
SELECT UserID 
FROM Users 
WHERE Start < currentTime AND End > currentTime 
AND ReasonID IN (SELECT ReasonID 
                 FROM ShiftReasons 
                 WHERE IsAbsence = 0)
```

Comment: This seems to compile. Will test to make sure it works. Will mark right if it does!

Comment: yeh should do, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
DECLARE @currentTime DateTime;
SET @currentTime = GETDATE();

SELECT UserID 
  FROM Users 
  WHERE currentTime between Start AND End
    AND ReasonID IN (SELECT s.ReasonID FROM ShiftReasons s WHERE s.IsAbsence = 0 )
```